# How to convert array object to single array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object array. I need to convert it single array without key.

I need array like this:

```
["test","test"]
```

I also need to remove that value if I got `undefined` instead of other value.

My code:

```js
const list = [
    {
        "type": "undefined"
    },
    {
        "type": "test"
    },
    {
        "type": "test"
    }
]

var findAndValue = list.map(Object.values);
console.log(findAndValue);
```

Comment: `list.map(({ type }) => type).filter(v => v !== "undefined")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)

Comment: Are you sure you want to test for undefined given as string value?

Comment: @RohitVerma Did you get a chance to look into the answer I added ? I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the value from one property, only return that property value from the `map` operation:

```js
const list = [
  { "type": "undefined" },
  { "type": "test" },
  { "type": "test" }
];
const result = list.map(x => x.type);
console.log(result);
```

To filter out the `"undefined"` string, use `filter`:

```js
const list = [
  { "type": "undefined" },
  { "type": "test" },
  { "type": "test" }
];
const result = list.map(x => x.type).filter(x => x !== "undefined");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

2 steps:

First extract all the values into a list

Second, remove any values you dont want

```
const values = list.map(({ type }) => type)
cosnt filteredValues = values.filter(val => val !== undefined)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `undefined` is a string type ? Ideally it should be just undefined and we can filter that out by using `Boolean` along with filter method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const list = [
  { "type": undefined },
  { "type": "test" },
  { "type": "test" }
];
const res = list.map(({ type }) => type).filter(Boolean);

console.log(res);
```